# Use GetElementsByClassName on created document

Tags: javascript, dom

I created a document in Javascript using

```
newdoc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument('Whatever')
```

and then I used

```
newdoc.innerHTML = document.innerHTML
```

to give him some code. The problem is that the DOM for newdoc doesn't seem to be fully formed and executing a function such as

```
newdoc.getElementsByClassName('somename')
```

on it yields undefined results. Do you know a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

`document` does not have `innerHTML` property.

You should use it on the `body`.

```
newdoc.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML;
```

Comment: How could I forget about it! I should RTFM the next time. Thanks.